# in jade, cannot get style @font-face to work

Tags: node.js, font-face, pug, stylus

from a working css file (generated by font-squirrel):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SnowTopCaps'; 
  src: url('/fonts/snowtopcaps-webfont.eot'); 
  src: url('/fonts/snowtopcaps-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/fonts/snowtopcaps-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/fonts/snowtopcaps-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/fonts/snowtopcaps-webfont.svg#snowtopcaps') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

trying to declare in `style` section in `jade` document:

```
...
style
  @font-face
    font-family
      | SnowTopCaps
    src
      | url('/fonts/snowtopcaps-webfont.woff') format('woff')
    font-weight
      | normal
    font-style
      | normal
    ...
```

but none of the `style` declaration is written to the generated `html`?

any anybody see what's missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is for HTML, not for css.
Use

```
style.
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'SnowTopCaps'; 
    src: url('/fonts/snowtopcaps-webfont.eot'); 
    src: url('/fonts/snowtopcaps-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('/fonts/snowtopcaps-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
      url('/fonts/snowtopcaps-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('/fonts/snowtopcaps-webfont.svg#snowtopcaps') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
```

Or use the :stylus filter

Comment: thanks! - I had completely spaced out the `stylus:` filter.  it simply replaces `style` and everything works great

Comment: I don't know if this did at the time of writing, but now requires a `.` after `style`.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765107/how-to-use-the-style-tag-with-jade-templates#answer-21777868 for more information

Comment: @mantagen It didn't, [`script` and `style` were special cased](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/878). Edited anyway.