# How to use the style tag with jade templates?

Tags: pug

This style code worked for me a few months back.  I have updated to the latest Jade NPM package and now it is not working.  Can some please assist me with the proper way to inline a style in a Jade template?

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
    head
        style(type='text/css')
           .ui-title {
                margin: 0.6em 10% 0.8em !important;
            }
```

I get this error on the closing }

```
unexpected text }
```

Comment: As always 10 minutes after I post to stack I figure it out.  I added a dot to the end of the style line

    style(type='text/css').

Is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the proper ways. There are three ways to put plain text inside a tag actually. You can find out more on [Putting Text Inside your Tags](http://jade-lang.com/tutorial/)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not inline css. This is just putting css in your head via a style tag. Inline css would be something like this: <p style="font-size:20px;">test</p>

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There are three ways of putting text inside your tags in Jade

#### 1. Put text just after the tag e.g.

```
h1 Some header text
```

And the output will be:

```
<h1>Some header text</h1>
```

#### 2. Put indented text below the tag with `|` e.g.

```
p
    | Some text goes 
    | here
```

And the output will be:

```
<p>Some text goes here</p>
```

#### 3. Suffix the tag with a dot and indent your text below (with no `|`) e.g.

```
p.
    This way 3rd way of putting 
    text inside
```

And the output will be:

```
<p>This way 3rd way of putting text inside</p>
```

---

So based on the above, the approach you chose (as in your comment) is correct (**option 3**).

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
    head
        style(type='text/css').
           .ui-title {
                margin: 0.6em 10% 0.8em !important;
            }
```

I hope that will help.

Answer (score 85):

This worked for me:

```
style.
  body {
    background-color: {{themeColor}};
  }
```

Got it from: https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-jade/issues/102 where the post suggests to use *"dot notation"*

Comment: Thanks I just had to change it to `#{themeColor}`

Answer (score 4):

Work for me in jade file

```
style(media='screen', type='text/css')
     @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        .container{
           max-width: 970px;
             }
          }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the way to do it (designer version)

```
include [some-html-include-name].html
```

Then in that include file put your `style` tag and styles

```
<style type="text/css">
/* your styles here */
```

Comment: This defeats the entire purpose of using a templating engine, namely that you don't have to write HTML. If you want to use an external file, use an external css file and `link` that.

Comment: The comment above was from a few years ago. At that time inlining critical css was becoming popular (I believe). The suggestion above is one way to inline a lot of styles. The developer could/can compile css and then inline it into a jade/pug include partial. Other comments above suggest other good ways to have inline styles within jade/pug templates. The example I posted above still seems like 1 way to do it. ~Thanks for your critique 